# What is the grammatical function of "as" here?

Tags: conjunctions

I know what it means, but what is the grammatical function of this "as" in the following sentence:

> The Russian law has roiled the classical world **as** few other political issues have in recent years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In traditional grammar the role *as* plays here is called a *subordinating conjunction*. In more recent grammars it is called a *subordinator* or *adverbial subordinator*.

It marks the following clause as ‘subordinate’ to the main clause, acting as an adverbial which modifies the main clause. In this particular case the subordinate clause is an adverbial ***of degree***; the Russian law has disturbed the world of classical music to a greater degree than all but a few other recent political issues.